# How do I convert city names to time zones?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, geocode, geonames, city

Sorry if this is repetitive, but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything that addresses my specific problem in R. I have a column with city names:

```
cities <-data.frame(c("Sydney", "Dusseldorf", "LidCombe", "Portland"))
colnames(cities)[1]<-"CityName"
```

Ideally I'd like to attach a column with either the lat/long for each city or the time zone. I have tried using the "ggmap" package in R, but my request exceeds the maximum number of requests they allow per day. I found the "geonames" package that converts lat/long to timezones, so if I get the lat/long for the city I should be able to take it from there.

Edit to address potential duplicate question: I would like to do this *without* using the ggmap package, as I have too many rows and they have a maximum # of requests per day.

Comment: Do you need a one to one ralationship?  What about cities that cross time zones?

Comment: @Jeffrey , one to one relationship would be ideal. I am assuming the likelihood of that happening in my data is low and if it does, its impact on the data negligible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get at least many major cities from the `world.cities` data in the `maps` package.

```
## Changing your data to a vector
cities <- c("Sydney", "Dusseldorf", "LidCombe", "Portland")

## Load up data
library(maps)
data(world.cities)

world.cities[match(cities, world.cities$name), ]
            name country.etc     pop    lat   long capital
36817     Sydney   Australia 4444513 -33.87 151.21       0
10026 Dusseldorf     Germany  573521  51.24   6.79       0
NA          <NA>        <NA>      NA     NA     NA      NA
29625   Portland   Australia    8757 -38.34 141.59       0
```

**Note:**     LidCombe was not included.
**Warning:**  For many names, there is more than one world city. For example,

```
world.cities[grep("Portland", world.cities$name), ]
          name country.etc    pop    lat    long capital
29625 Portland   Australia   8757 -38.34  141.59       0
29626 Portland         USA 542751  45.54 -122.66       0
29627 Portland         USA  62882  43.66  -70.28       0
```

Of course the two in the USA are Portland, Maine and Portland, Oregon.
`match` is just giving the first one on the list. You may need to use more information than just the name to get a good result.

Comment: I avoided the double city issue by splitting it up by country.  Obviously cities like "Portland" in the US will remain problematic, but it should be negligible. Thanks!

Comment: I almost included that in the answer - guessing that you were interested in Australia.

Comment: I am, but am just going to have to write a script for both US and Aus. Dang Portland, Aus is causing such a headache. Your script still saved me though!

Comment: This gets us from city name to lat / lon, but not from lat lon to time zone